# How do I implement a simultaneous irregular flood fill algorithm in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, flood-fill

I am looking to implement a flood fill algorithm that selects a number of random points and irregularly spreads all of the points' unique colours simultaneously, until all points are  assigned to a colour.
I have managed to fill one colour at a time, but haven't managed to get all of the points to fill at the same time.

(An example of the code I have tried to adapt would be something like [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis110/14fa/hw/hw09/FloodFill.java))

The only example of what I want, that I can find, is in JavaScript, which I do not have a decent enough understanding of at this moment to understand how it is achieved. If anyone can tell me how it works, I would very much appreciate a summary, you can find it [here](http://experilous.com/1/blog/post/procedural-planet-generation#elevation) (Although this page uses a sphere, while I will be using a 2D grid, which I can only imagine as being easier...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
});
and put your code inside the brackets